# Css width + position

Tags: html, html5, css3, width

Друзья, столкнулся с такой проблемой. Делаю чат на сайт. Блок с сообщениями имеет фикс.ширину (100%). Внутри этого блока лесенкой появляются блоки с сообщениями. Так вот проблема сама в том, что если у блоков с сообщениями убрать значение width - то эти гадины растягиваются на всю ширину родительского блока. А мне нужно,чтобы ширина каждого была исключительно под количество контента. Но не более чем 70% от ширины родителя.

Использую для родителя display:flex; direction- column.  Кроме того, пытался детям выставлять дисплей блок и позишн релатив,а далее лефт :0 , для входящих и райт:0,для исходящих. Но эти падлы на своих местах остаются ...

Помогите ...

Comment: Добавьте html и css код)

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так =)

```css
.chat {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 0 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 15px auto 0
}

.chat .name-chat {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000
}

.chat .message-field {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%
}

.chat .message-field .message {
  max-width: 70%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00f;
  align-self: flex-start;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px
}

.chat .message-field .my {
  background-color: #00f;
  align-self: flex-start
}

.chat .message-field .friend {
  background-color: green;
  align-self: flex-end
}

.chat .create-message {
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end
}

.chat .create-message form {
  margin: 15px 0
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
      <h2 class="name-chat">Супер чат</h2>
      <div class="message-field">
        <div class="my message">
          <p>Привет) Как дела? У меня сообщение макс длинны 70 процентов прикинь)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="friend message">
          <p>Приветик всё супер)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="friend message">
          <p>Ты как?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="my message">
          <p>Тоже хорошо)  </p>
        </div>
        <div class="my message">
          <p>Чем занимаешься?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="friend message">
          <p>Отдыхаю...   </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="create-message"> 
        <form action="#" method="#">
          <input type="text"/>
          <button>Отправить  </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: А классно сверстал на самом деле.

Comment: @EugenEray Если это то что нужно конечно =)